# Xamarin Style staticresource binding

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

would it be possible to databind a static resource in Xamarin Forms?
Something like

```
Style="{StaticResource {Binding foo, StringFormat='SomeStyle{0}'}}"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you probably want is a Value Converter that handles locating the StaticResource for you. Full Microsoft Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters).

On your XAML element, you'd do something like this:

```
<Entry Style="{Binding foo, Converter={StaticResource FooToStyleConverter}}"/>
```

Your converter would work something like this:

```
public class FooToStyleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var someValue = (string)value; // Convert 'object' to whatever type you are expecting

        // evaluate the converted value
        if (someValue != null && someValue == "bar")
            return (Style)App.Current.Resources["StyleOne"]; // return the desired style

        return (Style)App.Current.Resources["StyleTwo"];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Usually unused, but inverse the above logic if needed
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Lastly, set up your converter as a Static Resource in App.xaml (or as a local resource on the page) so your page can properly reference it

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingDemos">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
              <local:FooToStyleConverter x:Key="FooToStyleConverter" />
              ....
```