# Access Xamarin.Forms ListView Templated Controls in code-behind

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview, xamarin.forms-styles

I need to access controls which are in DataTemplate of ListView without firing any event on these controls.

On navigation to the page with the ListView, I need to dynamically change the style of these controls from the code-behind based on certain business logic and not any UI event.

Unable to find any example or documentation anywhere on internet.

So if anyone has come around similar scenario or know how to achieve this, please share. It would be a help.

Thanks

Comment: From what I understand you need to hook into `OnAppearing()` method of the `xaml.cs` file for the page and change the style property there.

Comment: Kindly add some code. That would help others understand the question better.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, I answered a similar question not too long ago. You might be able to use a ValueConverter to fulfill your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51197547/4597704